# Jenkins service won't start unless it has access to 178.255.83.1

Tags: jenkins, hudson, x509certificate, x509

We recently went through some network policy updates and I've discovered that my Jenkins server's jenkins service will no longer restart as expected (this worked fine prior to the policy updates).

There doesn't seem to be any logging information written on the service startup (no log files get updates).

Is there a list of external IPs that Jenkins needs to access in order to start up properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the logs, it seems as though part of the service start-up process is to contact one of the [OCSP Servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol). This seems to be related to certificate verification so it's probably legitimate traffic.

Once an exception was added for the target address (`http://178.255.83.1:80`), the Jenkins service started up without issues.

Comment: `dig -x 178.255.83.1` returns `ocsp.comodoca.com`. So it does look like a revocation related lookup.